# How to get cookie value in htaccess and add it as the first segment in url?

Tags: php, .htaccess, cookies

I have a Cookie named "**language**" which has the language code which my website would load in .

How can i check if it's set and add it as the first segment in my url , and set it if it's not set .

For example redirect **www.example.com** to  **www.example.com/en/** if the cookie is not set and to **www.example.com/ar/** if the cookie is set to "**ar**"

Answer (score 0):

In .htaccess, you can check whether a specific cookie  value exists using a **RewriteCond** and **%{HTTP_COOKIE}** variable.

To redirect based on the cookie value, you can use something like the following :

```
RewriteEngine on
#if cookie lang is not set, 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/en [L,R]
 #if the cookie lang  is set to "fr"  we will redirect to append the value at the end of the destination url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} ^lang=(fr)$
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/%1 [L,R]
Rewrite
```

Comment: it keeps adding /en forever till the browser stops it

Comment: Do you mean a **Redirect loop** ? It might be due to other rewriteRules you have in your htaccess.

Comment: my htaccess is empty except from this code :( , and it adds /en not something else , any tips ?
P.S my htaccess is exactly the same except the **example.com** part, its **127.0.0.1** other than that it's exactly the same

Comment: What happenes if you type http://example.com/en ? does it still return the loop error?